# Android Studio for Mac not opening

Tags: android-studio

I am not able to get Android Studio running on Mac, even after waiting for 15 minutes or so, it's still stuck on this screen:

[image]

What could be the problem?
Android Studio v2.2.3
MAC OSX 10.12.1 on MacBook Air

Comment: Do you find any solution of the same as I am facing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet :(

Comment: Did you get the solution? same issue on macbook air.

Answer (score 1):

Its just downloading necessary elements and SDK if necessary. So please check your internet connection and give it some time to finish the download.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, but I'm sharing it with others who may face the same issue.
For me, it was because I downloaded the wrong package (Appel ship pkg instead of Intel).
So you need to download the right pkg version.

If you're not sure which one, you can find it from the `about this mac`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. Found the solution..
Just delete all files related to AndroidStudio first.. you can refer 
https://gist.github.com/tahmidsadik112/f08356d14a85d898299a

Now install AndroidStudio again and if you are behind any proxy then after launch setup the proxy with authentication.. That's it!!!

Comment: The link is broken 

Comment: cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/
sudo ./studio

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a bit different experience, when I tried opening Android studio for the first time in my Mac. It allowed me to create a new Project and then while loading the IDE it got stuck -

[image]

The IDE was not getting opened. Apparently it seems like it was downloading something of size around 250 MB. I was stuck there for around 30 mins.

Then after 30 mins when the IDE opened, it threw an error and asked to `install missing platform and sync project`.

[image]

I clicked on the link and a new installation started of `Android SDK Platform 26`.

[image]

After the SDK Platform being installed it threw another error and asked to install the `SDK build tools`. On clicking the link the installation started:-

[image]

Finally after the installation of the `SDK build tools`, I was able to open the Android studio and access the code error free:

[image]

Happy Coding!! :)